# Get folder permissions in a user's mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

Is it possible to get a list of who has permissions to a folder in a user's mailbox in exchange 2007?

As far as I know it is not possible via exchange management shell. It is possible however in E2k10+ using the `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`. This is not available in E2k07.

If it is not possible in powershell, is there any other softwares available that can accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EWS managed API with PowerShell to get the folder delegates for the mailbox.  Glen Scales has some excellent articles on using this API with PowerShell, including one on getting delegate informtion:

http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/03/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to.html#!/2012/03/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to.html

Answer (score -2):

I just tried on Exchange 2007, and it works:

```
$permissions = Get-Mailbox $first.$last | Get-MailboxPermissions
```